# Android LiveData observes stale data after navigating back

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-livedata, android-mvvm, android-architecture-navigation

**Question:**

How can I prevent my livedata immediately receiving stale data when navigating backwards? I am using the `Event` class outlined [here](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150) which I thought would prevent this.

**Problem:**

I open the app with a login fragment, and navigate to a registration fragment when a live data email/password is set (and backend call says "this is a new account go register"). If the user hits the back button during the registration Android is popping back to login.
When the login fragment is *recreated* after a back press, it immediately fires the live data again with the stale backend response and I would like to prevent that.

LoginFragment.kt

```
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    subscribeToLoginEvent()
}

private fun subscribeToLoginEvent() {
    //When a back press occurs, we subscribe again and this instantly 
    //fires with the same data it used to leave the screen 
    //(a Resource<User> with status=SUCCESS, data = null)

    viewModel.user.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer { response ->
        Timber.i("login event observed....status:" + response?.status + ", data: " + response?.data)
        binding.userResource = response

        response?.let {
            val status = it.status
            val message = it.message

            if (status == Status.SUCCESS && it.data == null) {
                //This is a brand new user so we need to register now 
                navController()
                .navigate(LoginFragmentDirections.showUserRegistration()))
            }
            else if(status == Status.SUCCESS && it.data != null){
                goHome()
            }
        }
    })
}
```

LoginViewModel.kt

```
private val _loginCredentials: MutableLiveData<Event<Pair<String, String>>> = MutableLiveData()

val user: LiveData<Resource<User>> = Transformations.switchMap(_loginCredentials) {
    val data = it.getContentIfNotHandled()
    if(data != null && data.first.isNotBlank() && data.second.isNotBlank())
        interactor.callUserLoginRepo(data.first, data.second)
    else
        AbsentLiveData.create()
}
```

Comment: Are you really subscribing to the event immediately after creating the fragment, or was that only for demonstration purposes?

Comment: Yup, this seems to be the case in every sample I have found, either in `onActivityCreated` or `onViewCreated`. For example this is Google's "basic" sample: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/persistence/ui/ProductFragment.java

Comment: Well, there is no problem in doing it there, but I just find it weird that you are actually subscribing to a login event that actually tries to log the user when creating the fragment instead of when clicking a login button. But I'm probably missing some detail of your implementation. Anyway, I haven't used Livedata since the alpha release, but have you tried to override the onChanged method like they do in that example?

Comment: Ah okay yeah the login credentials in my case do come from another service. I believe `OnChanged` is overridden in the anonymous inner function of the Observer, that's basically my VM callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay there's two issues here which I hope helps somebody else.

- The first is that the `Event` class does not appear to work with transformations. I think it is because the Event is literally pointing to the wrong live data (`_login_credentials` vs `user`)
- The second problem is a little bit more fundamental but also blindingly obvious now. We are told all over the place that live data observations emit the latest data when a subscription is made to ensure you get the most up to date data. This means the way I am using live data here is simply incorrect, I can't subscribe to a login event, navigate somewhere, navigate back and re-subscribe because the ViewModel is rightfully giving me the latest data it has (because the login fragment was only detached, never destroyed).

**Solution**

The solution is to simply move the logic which performs the fetch one fragment deeper. So  instead of listening for user credentials + login click -> fetching a user -> and then navigating somewhere, I need to listen for user credentials + login click -> navigate somewhere -> and *then* start subscribing for my user live data. That way I can head back to the login screen as much as I want and not subscribe to some stale live data that was never destroyed. And if I go back to login and then forwards the subscription and fragment were destroyed so I will appropriately be getting new data in that case.